# Как задать любой тип переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Работаю фрилансером. Принял заказ на discord.py. Но не работает функция member.send(), потому что member = str (из консоли), а надо, чтобы member = discord.Member. Как сделать? Я знаю, что так можно сделать в аргументах в функции (ctx, member: discord.Member), но как это сделать просто в коде? Помогите, пожалуйста.
Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command start:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/antongorestov/Desktop/kwork_self_discord.py", line 25, in start
    await member.send("уи.")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1013, in send
    channel = await self._get_channel()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 299, in _get_channel
    ch = await self.create_dm()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 142, in general
    return await getattr(self._user, x)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/user.py", line 764, in create_dm
    data = await state.http.start_private_message(self.id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user
```

Код:

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    print('START')
    members = ctx.guild.members
    for member in members:
        member = discord.Member(member)
        try:
            await member.send("уи.")
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print('Отправилось!')
```

Comment: `Но не работает функция member.send()` - что конкретно означает "не работает"? Если возникает ошибка, добавьте ее в вопрос (полностью)

Comment: изменил, добавил ошибку

Comment: Так, и где у вас в коде `member = str (из консоли)`?

Comment: У вас переменная цикла `member` - это уже и есть объект типа `discord.Member`. А сообщение вы отправить не можете, потому что пользователь сам запретил это настройками приватности.  Об этом сказано в тексте ошибки

Comment: @denisnumb я создавал твинки, лазил в настройках приватности - все равно не отправлялось

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно обратиться ко всем участникам сервера:

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    print('START')
    for member in ctx.guild.members
        try:
            await member.send("уи.")
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print('Отправилось!')
```

Если нужно обратиться к какому-то определённому учатснику, получите объект участника с помощью `discord.utils.get()`

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    print('START')
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.member, id=ид участника, можно получить объект по имени, тогда используйте name=имя)
    try:
        await member.send("уи.")
    except:
        continue
    else:
        print('Отправилось!')
```

Надеюсь, я правильно понял, что нужно.